# Wine version conflict causing update manager to crash

Tags: apt, wine, package-management

I attempted to update wine from my existing 1.5 by installing 1.7 through apt-get but apparently it only partially succeeded. Now it looks like I'm trapped in a catch-22: When I try to install 1.7 it fails because 1.5 is already installed and is using some of the same files. I apparently can't remove either 1.5 or the installed portion of 1.7 because of the unmet dependency.

Running `apt-get -f install` makes it try to install `wine1.7-i386` but this fails:

```
Unpacking wine1.7-i386:i386 (from .../wine1.7-i386_1%3a1.7.11-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.7-i386_1%3a1.7.11-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/wine', which is also in package wine1.5 1.5.5-0ubuntu1~ppa1~oneiric1+pulse17
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.7-i386_1%3a1.7.11-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running apt-get autoclean after that removes wine1.7-i386 but either way I can't seem to get beyond that. Also, Ubuntu Update Manager crashes on load, obviously due to the same error.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which the error you get with `sudo apt-get remove wine1.5`?

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.11-0ubuntu1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: All I can figure is that since wine1.7 is partially installed, no packages can be changed until this is fixed.

I'm trying to do a `dpkg -r` on wine 1.7. Let's see if that works.

Comment: `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all wine1.7` then `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all wine1.5`

Comment: Which one solved it?

Comment: dpkg -r wine1.7, then apt-get remove wine1.5 and then apt-get install wine1.7.

Comment: Please, could you post as an answer, then copy all comments with  test results to your question and delete non needed ones. So it will be clean for new readers

Answer (score 0):

Remove wine1.5

```
sudo apt-get remove wine1.5
```

Then install wine1.7

```
sudo apt-get remove wine1.7
```

Comment: Tried that. See above.